# Should badges be shown per month/week/year on the Users page

Tags: feature-request, badges

On the [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) one can see the reputation users have gained the last week/month/quarter/year. If one selects [*all*](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), the total number of badges are shown per user as well.

The question/feature request is why does the site not shows the badges earned in the last week/month/quarter/year.

Comment: An active user does not (always) gain badges on a daily basis, unlike reputation.  Filtering badges seems impractical... (especially for non-active users)

Comment: @DominatorX: on a daily basis, it doesn't make any sense I agree. But by month/quarter/year, this makes more sense I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason:

> [image]

The tab is named "reputation". Not "badges" or "reputation and badges". Showing badges gained will render this name pointless.

As for badges showing when "all" is selected, it's just the ordinary user card, so it contains the badges as well.

If anything, a new tab can be added, dedicated to badges - but personally don't think it's important enough to be worth the team's time. SEDE query to show badge gain over time should be simple.